# How to get Dom object's content include itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to able to get #post content include itself. jQuery's html() method only return content that does not include itself.Trying to get parent object's html does not work in all situation because that object can have siblings.

What is solution for this ?

```
<div id="post">
     <div>content</div>
<div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Why do you want an elements html? That's bad practice.

Comment: He just wants it, that's all we have to worry about.

Answer (score 4):

#### Description

jQuery's `html()` gives you only the innerHTML right. You can do

```
$("#post")[0].outerHTML
```

to get the full html **but this is not crosser browser compatible**.

Check out this [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/6jy8u/)

#### You can use [this](http://darlesson.com/jquery/outerhtml/) plugin to get a cross browser compatible function `.outerHTML()`

#### More Information

- [jQuery - OuterHTML Plugin](http://darlesson.com/jquery/outerhtml/)
- [jQuery.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: Don't use an outerHTML plugin, provide an outerHTML shim instead.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand "shim".

Comment: As in my answer, that's a shim.

Answer (score 2):

You can clone the element in question and append the clone to a new element. Then you can get the HTML of the new element:

```
var html = $("<div>").append($("#post").clone()).html();
```

Comment: Yeah, expensive, but a nice, short, single line of code. Although perhaps a test for the native `outerHTML` property would be a good addition.

Comment: @Raynos - Why it is expensive ? Because of just cloning whole content ? If so it would be better wrap it inside a div and get html string of that conent would be better ?

Comment: you still need to clone it to do that. innerHTML is also expensive

Comment: Looking at http://jsperf.com/jquery-wrap-vs-append it seems that the other one liner: `$('#post').clone().wrap('<div>').parent().html();` is faster "in general" - I personally use .wrap, I'm usually taking an element generated from a template library then calling `wrap('<div/>').parent().html` (I don't need to clone since it's not in the DOM)

Answer (score 2):

you can `wrap` it around a virtual `div` using `clone` so infect you wont disturb the `DOM`.

you can try like this

```
$('#post').clone().wrap('<div>').parent().html();
```

Comment: Because it's the exact same as @James's answer. It's a duplicate.

Comment: 1st thing where did see that there should be dowtvote for duplicate answer??? second thing is, thats not exactly same a different syntax to do same thing.

Comment: look at other answers somebody has given exactly same answer after me and got upvoted... lolllzz

Comment: duplicate answers are noise. They don't need to exist. The best you can do is leave a comment saying you can also use `clone.wrap(div)` instead of `div.append(clone)`

Comment: Would agree, supplying an answer that does the same as other answers should not constitute a downvote as long they solve the problem at hand!

Comment: may be you can leave a comment saying its duplicate.. need not downvote.. downvote means the answer is not relevant or correct or to the point..http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down

Comment: that one line is too generic to prove plagiarized.

Comment: According to this: http://jsperf.com/jquery-wrap-vs-append - this answer is "generally" faster - so no it's not totally a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!Element.prototype.hasOwnProperty("outerHTML")) {
  Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, "outerHTML", {
    configurable: true,
    get: function getOuterHTML() {
      var html = this.innerHTML;
      var tag = "<" + this.tagName;
      var closeTag = "</" + this.tagName + ">";
      [].forEach.call(this.attributes, function (attr) {
        tag += attr.nodeName + '="' + attr.nodeValue + '"';
      });
      tag += ">";
      return tag + html + closeTag;
    }
  });
}
```

If outerHTML is not precent the following should shim it. This means you can just do

`document.getElementById("post").outerHTML;`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Raynos/XvF64/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
var elem = $("#post").clone().wrap('<div>').parent().html();
```

[Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/q5Kb6/)

Comment: Yes, for some reason the other answers did'nt appear until after I had posted this one!

Comment: I posted 2 min before than you :)

Comment: Yes, I'm not blind? As i was writing my answer and fiddling around in jsFiddle you posted your answer, and usually it gets updated without needing to refresh, but for some reason your answer did not appear on my screen until after I had posted my answer. Does that properly adress the problem for you ? It's not really a competition you know, even though it may seem like it at times!

Comment: opps.. I think i made you upset.. sorry for that.. I was just feeling like laughing with the situation thats all.. my intention wan not related to compition or anything.