# get content from element jquery not the name but the content

Tags: jquery

How to get the content from an element like a link

```
<a>hello!</a>
```

I want to get "hello!" with jquery.

Comment: Start here: http://learn.jquery.com

Comment: Please include the code that you have tried so far

Comment: try something there are answers already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871969/how-to-get-dom-objects-content-include-itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/)** or **[`html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/)**,

```
$('a').text();
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/G3pCK/)</kbd>

in case of multiple `a` tag set a `class` or `id` to the tag

```
<a id="link">hello!</a>
```

then use `id` selector

```
$('#link').text();
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/G3pCK/4/)</kbd>

or select `a` tag using index with the help of **[`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)** method

```
$('a').eq(0).text();
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/G3pCK/3/)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

try this code please:

```
$('a').text();
```

or this:

```
$('a').html();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DmTEG/)

Answer (score 1):

try something like

```
$("a").html();
```